# How do I supress the warning about "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously" when the interface I implement is async?

Tags: c#, async-await

I don't have anything in this method that is using await !  What does it want me to do ?

```
    public DatabaseHealthCheck(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync <------THIS WANTS ASNYC (HealthCheckContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection =
           new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("PwdrsConnectionRoot")))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();
            }
        }

        return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can add `await Task.Yield();` or use maybe use `await connection.OpenAsync()` instead

Comment: *"THIS WANTS ASNYC"* - This is incorrect. No interface can require that a method be `async`. However, it can require that the return type is `Task<T>`. That's what's happening here.

Comment: Just replace `connection.Open()` with [`await connection.OpenAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.openasync?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you do not want to remove the `async` keyword, and instead use the asynchronous counterparts of your underlying APIs, so that your code can be non-blocking whenever it is not CPU-bound. For example, as [mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943194/how-do-i-supress-the-warning-about-this-async-method-lacks-await-operators-an#comment104145187_58943194), you can use `connection.OpenAsync()` instead of `connection.Open()`:

```
public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection =
       new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("PwdrsConnectionRoot")))
    {
        try
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();
        }
    }

    return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();
}
```

However, if you *really* want to just remove the `async` keyword and leave your implementation alone, then you'll need to explicitly wrap the return values and exceptions with `Task`:

```
private HealthCheckResult CheckHealthImpl(HealthCheckContext context,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection =
       new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("PwdrsConnectionRoot")))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();
        }
    }

    return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();
}

public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    try
    {
        return Task.FromResult(CheckHealthImpl(context, cancellationToken));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Task.FromException(e);
    }
}
```

That should properly implement the interface, and preserve the equivalent behavior to your prior `async` function.

Answer (score -1):

If you need the method to remain `async`, there are a couple ways of solving your issue:

1. the easiest way would be to return a `await Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Healthy())` with your static result.
2. you can also suppress specific types of warnings inside Visual Studio as can be seen on [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2019#suppress-warnings-for-nuget-packages). TLDR: you change it in the project’s properties.

Let me know if this helped!

Take care.

Comment: `async` has nothing to do with implementing the interface. `async` is merely an implementation detail of asynchronous functions. The part of the contract that must be fulfilled is the return type of `Task<HealthCheckResult>`

Comment: The only time you should use `await Task.FromResult` is if another part of your method awaits something actually asynchronous. Otherwise, you can just remove the `async` keyword and return `Task.FromResult(...)` to save some CPU cycles.